# Can AVFoundation play Audio and get Details of it On the IOS 5.0 Simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

Can the Above be Done using only AVFoundation.framework?

i Tried doing a few experiment but i can't really get it to work

(sorry newbie here please do tell me where to put the codes at Example: ViewController or the MainView)

These are my code,(UI Components are inside as i'm do not want use interface builder)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSError *error;
        buttonPlay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 350, 100, 50)];

        buttonPlay.text = @"Play";

        // Get the file path to the song to play.
        NSString* path;
        NSURL* url;

        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bring_Me_To_Life.mp3" ofType:nil];
        url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        //Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];

        // Preloads the buffer and prepares the audio for playing.
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
        audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];

        [self addSubview:buttonPlay];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(CGPoint)location{
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(buttonPlay.frame, location)){
        NSLog(@"Dec from Chl %f",[audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:0]);
        NSLog(@"Length of Clip %f",[audioPlayer duration]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

Comment: Thanks for this i pop it in and got an OSStatus Error 119.... and i immediately know it is an audio file error Thanks a lot.